# How to toggle div's on and of on a daily basis?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project, my employer wants to change his daily offer every day in a week, now I have tried to get my 7 div's in `js` and turn them on and off whit if statements ex:

```
var day = new Date().get Day()
if(day == 5){
div.style.display = "block";
//all the other div's would be display none//
```

I tried searching for a similar problem online but there is no solution.
I hope I clearly explained the problem. keep in mind that I am currently a beginner in `js` and i would love to hear out a more simpler solution.

Comment: You can by default set all elemenst to hidden then depending on the day make the ones you need visible. Set them to hidden in th html div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will display offer div based on today's day.
I have used jQuery to keep the script short and simple.
ask if you don't get any part.

**Edited:** Added one more easy solution without jQuery

```
// Solution without jQuery.
// get div for all days. It gives you an array of div
var allDaysDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('weekDay');

// hide all div 
allDaysDiv[0].style.display = 'none';
allDaysDiv[1].style.display = 'none';
allDaysDiv[2].style.display = 'none';
allDaysDiv[3].style.display = 'none';
allDaysDiv[4].style.display = 'none';
allDaysDiv[5].style.display = 'none';
allDaysDiv[6].style.display = 'none';

// get numeric for today
var day = new Date().getDay();

// display today's div
document.getElementById(day).style.display = 'block';
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".weekDay").hide(); // hide all div with class as 'weekDay' 
  var day = new Date().getDay();  // get numeric for today, 0-6 for sunday to saturday
  $("#"+day).show();  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="weekDay" id="0">  Sunday Offer</div>
  <div class="weekDay" id="1">  Monday Offer</div>
  <div class="weekDay" id="2">  Tuesday Offer</div>
  <div class="weekDay" id="3">  Wednesday Offer</div>
  <div class="weekDay" id="4">  Thursday Offer</div>
  <div class="weekDay" id="5">  Friday Offer</div>
  <div class="weekDay" id="6">  Saturday Offer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this one worked for me, don't quite understand the syntax since its jQuery but i just copied what you did :)

Comment: One more question , could this be done with if and else the way i started?

Comment: Yes of course, you can have if-else blocks. I have added one more easy example without jQuery. But my suggestion is, once you are confident in JavaScript start learning jQuery alongside. It is very easy to learn and amazingly powerful. You can do a lot  with less code.

Comment: Can you point me to a youtube chanell or maybe some online tutorials for learning jQuery ( chanell or tutorial that you think is good ) ?

Comment: Here is [step by step tutorial with interactive examples.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp)  

And here is a [Video tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap)

Comment: And one more thing, this part of the code i dont understand, what did you grab and why display it like this (not the block but document.getElemntByID) document.getElementById(day).style.display = "block" ?

Comment: By the way thank you very much you really helped me alot :)

Comment: if you observe HTML, there is **id** attribute for every div tag, like id="0". 
Line `var day = new Date().getDay();` assigns a numeric value of today to **day** variable(e.g. 6 for Saturday). 
**getElementById** is used to select any element by it's id. 
So finally, line `document.getElementById(day).style.display = 'block';` selects element(div) which has id="6"(Today is saturday, so **day** has value 6) and changes it's display style.
You are always welcome. Objective of this community is to help earch other to grow strong. So Keep growing.

Answer (score 0):

I would give all your divs unique IDs and the same class name.

```
<div id="offer0" class="offer">Content</div>
<div id="offer1" class="offer">Content</div>
<div id="offer2" class="offer">Content</div>
<div id="offer3" class="offer">Content</div>
<div id="offer4" class="offer">Content</div>
<div id="offer5" class="offer">Content</div>
<div id="offer6" class="offer">Content</div>
```

When you do you check for what day it is, set display of every div with that class name to be 'none', then get the div you want by ID and change it back to block.

```
// gets day of the week, Sunday = 0    
var day = new Date().getDay()

// gets a collection of divs with the class name "offer"
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('offer')
var len = divs.len

// loop through the divs we grabbed above and set their display to "none"    
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    divs[i].style.display = 'none';
}

// get the element by it's ID using the day var we stored above
document.getElementById('offer' + day).style.display = 'block'
```